# How to delete macro in VS 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I updated VS 2015 to VS 2017. When I open old projects or Qt projects.The VC++ directories will include the  two paths showed in the picture. But my projects does not use opencv, and I have deleted all related opencv ,including System environment variable. however there are still here,causing projects does not work.How to delete the two macros.

[image: VC++ directories]

Comment: This suggests these are worked out, based on the inherited values - you do have that check box ticked. Try unticking it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. modify or delete the files in C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0